# Assign elements of one list of lists to elements of another list of lists while keeping a sum constraint

Tags: python, list

I have two lists of lists and an empty list:

```
 list_a = [[1], [6], [2]]
    list_b = [[2], [8], [3]]
    list_c = []
```

By extending the lists in list_b, I want to assign the values in the lists of list_a to the values in the lists of list_b in such a way that, in the end, the sum in each of the lists in list_b is smaller or equal than 8. If a value contained in a list of list_a cannot be assigned to list_b that way, it shall be appended to list_c. Each list in list_a can only be assigned to one list in list_b.
A possible result would be:

```
list_b = [[2, 1, 2], [8], [3]]
list_c = [[6]]
```

How can I do this in Python? I know that there are many possible results. I would be fine with a solution that gives one possible result. Please consider that the solution should also run for problems, in which the lists in list_a and list_b contain more than one value (so you might have to sum them up with `sum(list_x)`).

I tried to solve it with a nested loop and two if statements inside, but I could not get even close to an acceptable result.

Comment: What algorithm are you trying to implement? Are you able to describe the steps of the algorithm in your own words on paper?

Comment: The answer below was already sufficient. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
for item in list_b:
    a_index = 0
    stuff = True
    running = item[0]
    while stuff:
        cand = sum(list_a[a_index])
        if cand + running <= 8:
            item.append(list_a.pop(a_index))
            running += cand
        else:
            a_index += 1
        stuff = a_index < len(list_a)
for remainder in list_a:
    list_c.append(list_a.pop(0))
```